# Ordering boxplots using SGplot in SAS

Tags: graph, sas, boxplot

I'm generating vertical boxplots in SAS using SGPLOT procedure, following is the code. I cannot order the boxplots by various categories, I'd like to order them by ascending mean of the variable being measured "cholesterol", but cannot seem to make that happen. Also, i'd love to be able to change the names of the various levels of category variable "weight_status" and perhaps even consider plotting the boxplots sorted alphabetically.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.heart;
title "Cholesterol Distribution by Weight Class";
vbox cholesterol / category=weight_status GROUPORDER= descending;
run;
title
```

Could someone assist with this?

Comment: You should either provide a sample `temp` dataset, or rewrite this to work off of a `sashelp` dataset (`sashelp.class`, `sashelp.cars`, etc.).

Comment: Sure, Joe -i made the change for the code to work on the sashelp dataset. I need to be able to show the resulting 3 boxplots by their mean (ascending). Also, id like to be able to change the "display" name of the various category values e.g. normal to N, overweight to O and underweight to U without actually changing this in the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

### Correcting your error

To use `GROUPORDER=`, you must use `GROUP=` instead of categories, so this works:

```
title "Cholesterol Distribution by Weight Status";
proc sgplot data=sashelp.heart;
    where Weight_Status NE '';
    vbox cholesterol / 
        GROUP=weight_status  
        GROUPORDER= descending;
run;
title
```

I had to add the where clause because missing categories are suppressed but missing groups are not.

### Sorting by the mean of the variable being measured

To do this, you must add that mean to the dataset, for instance this way:

```
proc sql;
    create view temp_heart as
    select individu.weight_status, cholesterol, group_mean
    from   sashelp.heart individu inner join
        (   select weight_status, mean(cholesterol) as group_mean
            from   sashelp.heart
            group by weight_status ) collection 
        on individu.weight_status EQ collection.weight_status;
quit;
```

I have two ways for you to display this

#### Use mean cholesterol as category and weight_status as group

Numerical categories are sorted in numerical order, so that does the job but to display also your weight classes in the legend, I use them as the group

```
proc sgplot data=temp_heart;
    where Weight_Status NE '';
    vbox cholesterol / 
        Category=group_mean
        GROUP=weight_status  ;
run;
```

Now this is quick and dirty, I agree, so I have another option

#### Use mean cholesterol as category, but put a format on it

Use `Proc Format` to create a format for the averages and then use that format

```
proc sql;
    create table temp_means as 
    select 'mean2status' as fmtname
         , mean(cholesterol) - 1E-8 as start
         , mean(cholesterol) + 1E-8 as end
         , weight_status as label
    from   sashelp.heart
    group by weight_status;
quit;

proc format cntlin=temp_means (where=(label NE '')) cntlout=temp_check;
run;

proc sgplot data=temp_heart (where=(weight_status NE ''));
    format group_mean mean2status.;
    vbox cholesterol / 
        category=group_mean;
run;
```

Unfortunately, I had to use an interval of 2E-8 wide around the averages before it worked.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. What is "individu" in your proc sql code? i cannot find a variable/dataset by that name anywhere.

Comment: I also cannot select more variables when creating the view - i get an error. Cannot even subset it in the select statement within the parenthesis

Comment: `individu` and  `collection` are aliasses for sashelp.heart and the subquery